# scala type error for class with map member typed with existential type

Tags: scala

I have a type system problem with scala that I can't understand. The problem is illustrated with the snippet below. What is the correct approach to be able to have a map member in a class that can have keys of type A or subtypes of A?
I think the second approach is correct but I get errors when I try to get elements from the map. Has this something to do with existential types?

```
sealed abstract class MyBaseType
case class Concrete1() extends MyBaseType
case class Concrete2() extends MyBaseType

case class DictVariant1(data: Map[MyBaseType, Double])
case class DictVariant2(data: Map[_ <: MyBaseType, Double])

object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val d = List((Concrete1(), 3.5)).toMap

    /* this fails with:
     * type mismatch;  
     * found: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Concrete1,Double]  
     * required: Map[MyBaseType,Double] 
     * Note: Concrete1 <: MyBaseType, but trait Map is invariant in type A. 
     * You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: MyBaseType`. 
     * (SLS 3.2.10)
     * 
     */
    val dv1 = DictVariant1(d)
    dv1.data.get(d)

    /* Works fine */
    val dv2 = DictVariant2(d)

    /* this fails with:
     * type mismatch;  
     * found: d.type (with underlying type scala.collection.immutable.Map[Concrete1,Double])  
     * required: _$1    
     * 
     */
    dv2.data.get(Concrete1())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you explicitly require getting the keys back out as the statically correct subtype (which seems unlikely), then the following will work:

```
case class DictVariant1(data: Map[MyBaseType, Double])
val d = List((Concrete1() : MyBaseType, 3.5)).toMap
val dv1 = DictVariant1(d)
```

Using a type ascription forces `Concrete1()` to be seen as an instance of the base type; you'd get the same effect if you added an explicit type to `d`:

```
val d : Map[MyBaseType, Double] = ....
```

Or if you put multiple entries in such that the type inferencer picks the base type:

```
val d = List((Concrete1(), 3.5), (Concrete2(), 4.5)).toMap
```

The 'get' you use is always going to fail, however, because you're trying to use the whole `Map` as an index: it works fine if you provide a sensible key:

```
dv1.data.get(Concrete1())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll edit my source since the get was an error. Of course it was the key I was after, not the map itself.